# Is the String.Split method broken in Mono 5.20.1 (on Windows OS)?

Tags: c#, mono

- Running version 5.20.1 of Open Mono x64 on Windows 10 -

The String.Split method in mono keeps giving a runtime error.
The following code has been simplified down to focus in on the problem.

```
using System;

public class stringSplit{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string splitIn = "test1,test2";
    string[] splitOut = splitIn.Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine(splitOut);
  }
}
```

The code compiles but gives runtime error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String[] System.String.Split(Char, System.StringSpitOptions)'.
>     at stringSplit.Main()

Comment: MissingMethodExceptions are normally a hint that your installation is borked; how did you install Mono?

Comment: What compiler do you use and what framework version do you compile against? Looks like your compiler chooses an overload that's present in the chosen framework, but is missing from Mono

Comment: @knotce went to mono-project.com/download, downloaded and installed.

Comment: @CodeCaster using Mono version 5.20.1.19 (current stable) and am compiling from the mono command prompt (command prompt link that comes with mono install that sets path.) Using Atom editor unmodified, no plugins currently. That's why it doesn't make sense to me, I have as streamlined of a setup as one can, all new and on a new install of Win10. It does look like I'll have to uninstall and reinstall however. I never installed Visual Studio so the only framework for the most part should be ones installed by Mono itself or other apps on the system.

Comment: Addendum: just checked path and Mono\bin is the first item listed.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this strange case.
I solved this by creating an additional char array to specify separating symbols.

```
using System;

public class stringSplit{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string splitIn = "test1,test2";
    char[] separators = { ','};
    string[] splitOut = splitIn.Split(separators);
    Console.WriteLine(splitOut);
  }
}
```